# What is the filepath that a "Read CSV" operator needs to read a file from RapidMiner Server?

Tags: filepath, rapidminer

I have a RM Server running on a VM (Ubuntu) on top of my Win10 machine.
I have a process to read a .csv file and write its contents on a MySQL database on a MySQL Server which also runs on the same VM.

The problem is that the read file operator does not seem to be able to find the file.

Scenario1.
When I try as location-name in the read csv operator `../data/myFile.csv`
and run the process on Server I am getting `Failed to execute initialization process: Error executing process /apps/myApp/process/task_read_csv_to_db: The file 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/../data/myFile.csv (No such file or directory)' does not exist.`

Scenario2.
When I try as location-name in the read csv operator `/apps/myApp/data/myFile.csv`
and run the process on Server I am getting `Failed to execute initialization process: Error executing process /apps/myApp/process/task_read_csv_to_db: The file 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /apps/myApp/data/myFile.csv (No such file or directory)' does not exist.`

What is the right filepath that I should give to the Read CSV operator?

---

Just to update with the answer. After David's suggestion, I resulted in storing the .csv file outside of the `/rapidminer-server-home/data/repository` since every remote repository seems to be depicted with an integer instead of its original name, making the use of the actual full path of the file not usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, the issue is that depending on the location of the JobAgent that is executing your process, the relative path might be varying.
Is `/apps/myApp/data/myFile.csv` the correct path to the file? If not, I would suggest to use the absolute path to the file. Hope this helps.

Best,
David

Comment: I was trying to find the absolute path to the file but with no luck. I guess that it has to be somewhere in the `/root/rapidminer-server/rapidminer-server-9.5.0/` or the `/root/rapidminer-server/rapidminer-server-home/` but I wasn't able to find it. Could you or someone else please, tell me where exactly a new remote repository is created on a linux system?